# Ошибка при установке JHipster

Tags: linux

Второй день смотрю на это:

```
mihail@mihail-eMachines-E725:~$ sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster
[sudo] password for mihail: 
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

> deasync@0.1.4 install /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/deasync
> node ./build.js

make: Вход в каталог `/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/deasync/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o
make: g++: Команда не найдена
make: *** [Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o] Ошибка 127
make: Выход из каталога `/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/deasync/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-27-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v6.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
/usr/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-27-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-jhipster"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! deasync@0.1.4 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.4 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the deasync package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs deasync
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls deasync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mihail/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
mihail@mihail-eMachines-E725:~$
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @enzo Безгранично благодарен!!! Проблемма решена командой 'sudo apt-get install g++'

Comment: @enzo, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш комментарий в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение `make: g++: Команда не найдена` говорит о том, что не установлен компилятор C++. Соответственно, обрывается установка **nodeJS** модуля **deasync**.

Для установки компилятора (в Debian-based дистрибутиве) необходимо выполнить команду:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

или

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Последняя устанавливает необходимые компоненты для сборки приложений из исходных файлов в Debian, в том числе `g++`.